# What is the difference between Kafka connect and Confluent Kafka?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-kafka-dotnet

Currently, I have Apache Kafka in Docker. I am using a confluent—Kafka client for connecting the Kafka Topics(Producer and Subscriber) from the the.Net core application. Today I came to know that Kafka connect can be used for this. After all the research, I concluded that Kafka connect is not available for .net which can be used in Java only. So anyone please help me to understand the difference in the following manner?

- License
- Platform
- Features
- Support

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as "Confluent Kafka".

There's [Confluent Platform, which includes Apache Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/apache-kafka-vs-confluent/) + Kafka Connect scripts, both of which are Apache 2.0 Licensed.

The library named `confluent-kafka-dotnet` is only a Producer/Consumer/AdminClient C# equivalent to the `kafka-clients` JVM library. The Connect Framework is an abstraction over this.

> Kafka client for connecting the Kafka Topics(Producer and Subscriber) from the the.Net core application. Today I came to know that Kafka connect can be used for this.

Not quite. Kafka Connect is used for connecting to external systems, such as filesystems, web servers, or databases.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/concepts.html